# How to host a website in Amazon ec2 windows server 2008 r2

Tags: amazon-ec2, windows-server-2008-r2, web-hosting, domain-name

I have created a virtual server in amazon es2. My server is windows server 2008 r2. it already has iis installed. I have also hosted my a site. Problem is , I do not know what is my name server is?

I have a domain suppose xyz.com. Now what the name server I will put in my domain name registration website? I could not find where to get the name server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use Amazon's [Route53](http://aws.amazon.com/route53/), which is their DNS solution.  Log into AWS, choose Route53 from the main menu, and within Route53 you'll want to create a Hosted Zone for xyz.com, then within that zone create an A record for www.xyz.com that is an alias for your ec2 instance.  When you create the hosted zone it will list the names of the DNS servers that you will want to use.